# Python classes -- attributes not visible

Tags: python

I'm trying to create 2 objects,

1. `A` by defining as a regular Python class
2. `B` by dynamically creating properties.

Once both the classes are created, I'm trying to print their dictionary and noticed that for Class B which is dynamically created the attribute "X" is not listed.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0


x = A(1,2)
print "Class A directory =",dir(x)

class B:pass
B().x = 5
y = B()
print "Class A directory =",dir(y)
```

Output

```
Class A directory = ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'x', 'y']
Class B directory = ['__doc__', '__module__']
```

Comment: There are no metaclasses here, only regular classes and instances.

Answer (score 8):

`B()` creates an instance of B.  When you do `B().x = 5`, you create an instance, set the `x` attribute, and then discard the instance (since you didn't assign the `B()` to anything).  Then you create another instance with `y = B()`, but this instance isn't affected by what you did to the previous one.

You can do:

```
y = B()
y.x = 5
```

However, you have a couple terminological misunderstandings.  In both of your examples you're calling `dir` on the *instance*, not the class.  If you print `dir(A)` or `dir(B)`, you'll see that the `x` attribute is not listed in either case, since it exists only on instances of the class, not on the class itself.

Also, it's not really correct to say that B is "created dynamically" while A is "defined as a regular Python class".  They're both regular Python classes.  It's just that class A is defined to create an attribute `x` in initialization, while class `B` isn't (and you then add an attribute to its instance later).  Class B is still a normal Python class, it just has different defined behavior than A.  (Note that you could add extra attributes to instances of A just like you did for B, by doing something like `x = A(); x.newAttr = "blah"`.)

Also, you mention metaclasses in your title, but you're not using metaclasses at all here.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `A` is a new-style class while `B` is an old-style class.